# How can I change the direction of jHtmlArea

Tags: right-to-left, direction, jhtmlarea

I'm using jHtmlArea in my project. I want to write in "Right To Left" direction mode. But it only supports Left to Right.
How can I do in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer by myself.

I attached a css file to my jHtmlArea. then set the direction in it.

```
$('textarea').htmlarea({
    css: "/MyRootFolder/Styles/jHtmlArea/jHtmlArea.Editor.css"
});
```

jHtmlArea.Editor.css :

```
body 
{
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
    margin: 2px;
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```